# When freeing a pointer for a nested struct getting Segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, free

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMESIZE 20
#define LINESIZE 1024

typedef struct name name;
struct name
{
    char last[NAMESIZE];    /* last name */
    char first[NAMESIZE];   /* first name*/
};

typedef struct record record;
struct record
{
    name name;
    int score;
};

typedef struct record_list record_list;
struct record_list
{
    record *data;   /* the dynamic array of records */
    size_t nalloc;  /* number of records allocated */
    size_t nused;   /* number of records in use */
};

void list_init(record_list *list)
{
    list -> data = 0;
    list -> nalloc = 0;
    list -> nused = 0;
}

int list_insert(record_list *list, const record *rec)
{   
    size_t newSize;
    record *tmp;

    if(list -> nalloc == list -> nused)
    {
        if(list -> nalloc == 0)
        {
            newSize = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            newSize = 2 * list -> nalloc;
        }

        tmp = realloc(list -> data, newSize * sizeof(record));

        if(tmp == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        list -> data = tmp;
        list -> nalloc = newSize;
    }

    list -> data[list -> nused++] = *rec;

    return 1;
}

void list_destroy(record_list *list)
{
    printf("Attempting Deletion");
    free(list->data);
    free(list->nalloc);
    free(list->nused);

    list -> data = 0;
    list -> nalloc = 0;
    list -> nused = 0;
}

int main(void){
    record_list list;
    record *r;
    name n;

    int score;

    char input[NAMESIZE];
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    char lname[NAMESIZE];


    list_init(&list);
    while(input != NULL) {
        printf("Please enter a value for Name: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        strcpy(input, name);
        printf("Enter last name: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        strcpy(input, lname);
        printf("Enter score: ");
        scanf("%d", &score);

        r=(record*)malloc(sizeof(record));
        if(r == NULL){
            printf("There isn't enough memory.\n");
        }
         strcpy(n.first, name);
         strcpy(n.last, lname);
         r -> name = n;
         list_insert(&list, r);
         printf("\n");
         printf("Choose next action:\n");
         printf("\tTo add more type \"add\";\n");
         printf("\tTo delete all records type \"del\";\n");
         scanf("%s", input);
         if(strcmp(input, "del") == 0){
            list_destroy(&list);
            printf("Deleted");
            break;
        }
    }


    return 1;
}
```

I am working on a small lab exercise where we make a struct, fill it and clear it if the user needs to. Yesterday everything worked but today I seem to either have not saved it or broke something because I am getting a ton of errors.
Here is an example of the error I'm getting:
[image]

Essentially when I call a method

```
void list_destroy(record_list *list);
```

it crashes before reaching the first print statement which means I am doing something wrong with the method call.

Summarized question: What could be causing the segmentation fault (where am I accessing incorrect memory) Or how else can I clear my struct memory without using free?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to locate exactly where the crash happens in your code. Then look for stray or non-null pointers that should be null.

Comment: We are supposed to use a text editor and cygwin only. ANSI standard as well.

Comment: Also note that in C, `NULL` and `0` may not actually be the same. Most implementations have them equivalent, but they are not really the same (`NULL` is a pointer and `0` is an `int`).

Comment: Next to the compiler and a good editor, the most useful tool for any programmer is a debugger.

Comment: Because you're freeing things you didn't allocate with malloc.

Comment: Actually, when `0` is converted to a pointer it is guaranteed to equal to `NULL`.

Comment: @TheUnknown please do not edit the answer into the question, or edit the question to say "Solved" etc.  That just makes it confusing for people coming to this question after that point. Instead, you can accept an answer by clicking the check-mark under the voting score beside that answer; and you can post the working code as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This should tell what your problem is:

```
code.c: In function 'list_destroy':
code.c:74: warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast
code.c:75: warning: passing argument 1 of 'free' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

You're trying to free int fields. You can't free them because they are not pointers to memory blocks.

So, remove these lines of code:

```
free(list->nalloc);
free(list->nused);
```

Comment: That sounds great but  I am really new to this. How would one go about clearing said memory.

Edit: Still crashing.

Comment: @TheUnknown Only `free` what you `malloc`!

Comment: @TheUnknown what do you mean clearing? (You can only `free` things allocated by `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`))

Comment: Basically we when the user enters "del" I need to have the struct be empty.

Comment: If you want to clear the fields, why not do `list->nalloc = 0; list->nused = 0;`. `free` doesn't clear the fields, it just frees the data pointed to by a pointer.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I made it work. I will post the working code in my question.

Comment: Please, consider posting a new answer instead.